# Which arts use the Naginata?

Tags: weapons

I have been interested in the Naginata. Which arts train with it? I have seen the term Naginatajutsu, is this a practiced art on its own or simply a part of another art?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the Naginata in martial arts, *naginatajutsu*, is practiced in Bujinkan, Koryū (古流) and Kobudō (古武道) schools.

Comment: Are any practiced in the states?

Comment: @Btuman I do not live in the states. But you should contact Johnny Long at <johnny@ihackstuff.com>—he's a penetration tester/security engineer—and ask him where [he practices Bujinkan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfFELeCP-oA)—you only need to watch 2 minutes into the video to verify.

Comment: @Btuman - The Bujinkan has several schools in the states, including many in the midwest. [There appear to be several in the Detroit area.](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mza/UM_links.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just a brief introductory list for you:

- 肥後古流 *Higo ko-ryū*
- 天道流 *Tendo-ryū*
- 戸田派武甲流 *Toda-ha Bukō-ryū*
- 九鬼神伝流 *kukishinden-ryū*
- 日下捕手開山竹内流 *Hinoshita Toride Kaizan Takenouchi-ryū*
- 立身流 *Tatsumi-ryū*,
- 水鷗流 *Suiō-ryū*
- 柳生心眼流 *Yagyū Shingan-ryū*
- 天真正伝香取神道流 *Tenshin Shōden Katori Shintō-ryū*
- 鹿島新当流 *Kashima Shintō-ryū*
- 馬庭念流 *Maniwa Nen-ryū*
- 駒川改心流 *Komagawa Kaishin-ryū*
- 鹿島神流 *Kashima-Shinryū*
- and a branch of 楊心流 *Yōshin-ryū*

all teach 薙刀術 *naginatajutsu*.

The *bujinkan*, *jinenkan*, and *genbukan* teach *naginatajutsu* through 九鬼神伝流 *kukishinden-ryū*.

If you're looking for a sport form (like *kendo*), you might look into the [International Naginata Federation](http://www.naginata.org/inf/inf.html).

Answer (score 1):

I do [Seishinkan Bujutsu](http://seishinkan.info/), and we use a naginata as an optional part of the training.